# JavaScript Regex - Find all possible matches, even in already captured matches

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I'm trying to obtain *all possible matches* from a string using a regex with JavaScript. It appears that my method of doing this is not matching parts of the string that have already been matched.

Variables:

```js
var string = 'A1B1Y:A1B2Y:A1B3Y:A1B4Z:A1B5Y:A1B6Y:A1B7Y:A1B8Z:A1B9Y:A1B10Y:A1B11Y';

var reg = /A[0-9]+B[0-9]+Y:A[0-9]+B[0-9]+Y/g;
```

Code:

```js
var match = string.match(reg);
```

All matched results I get:

```js
A1B1Y:A1B2Y
A1B5Y:A1B6Y
A1B9Y:A1B10Y
```

Matched results I want:

```js
A1B1Y:A1B2Y
A1B2Y:A1B3Y
A1B5Y:A1B6Y
A1B6Y:A1B7Y
A1B9Y:A1B10Y
A1B10Y:A1B11Y
```

In my head, I want `A1B1Y:A1B2Y` to be a match along with `A1B2Y:A1B3Y`, even though `A1B2Y` in the string will need to be part of two matches.

Comment: A lookahead would get you the matches you want, but unfortunately it doesn't return the part of the lookahead. I haven't found a way to capture the lookahead with javascript. Maybe there is, don't know. Your regex with lookahead would be: var reg = /A[0-9]+B[0-9]+Y(?=:A[0-9]+B[0-9]+Y)/g;

Comment: Maybe `string.split(":")` and then looping over the array might give you a better result.

Comment: @nhahtdh tried that with match(), but of course the lookahead is a separate capture. Duh! Beautiful answer. :-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Without modifying your regex, you can set it to start matching at the beginning of the second half of the match after each match using [`.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and manipulating the regex object's `lastIndex` property.

```
var string = 'A1B1Y:A1B2Y:A1B3Y:A1B4Z:A1B5Y:A1B6Y:A1B7Y:A1B8Z:A1B9Y:A1B10Y:A1B11Y';
var reg = /A[0-9]+B[0-9]+Y:A[0-9]+B[0-9]+Y/g;
var matches = [], found;
while (found = reg.exec(string)) {
    matches.push(found[0]);
    reg.lastIndex -= found[0].split(':')[1].length;
}

console.log(matches);
//["A1B1Y:A1B2Y", "A1B2Y:A1B3Y", "A1B5Y:A1B6Y", "A1B6Y:A1B7Y", "A1B9Y:A1B10Y", "A1B10Y:A1B11Y"]
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/upesek/5/edit)

---

As per Bergi's comment, you can also get the index of the last match and increment it by 1 so it instead of starting to match from the second half of the match onwards, it will start attempting to match from the second character of each match onwards:

```
reg.lastIndex = found.index+1;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/upesek/7/edit)

The final outcome is the same. Though, Bergi's update has a little less code and performs slightly [faster](http://jsperf.com/setting-lastindex-inside-exec-performance). `=]`

Comment: Nice, that's much better than lookahead, capturing groups etc. Btw, `reg.lastIndex = found.index+1;` should be enough and makes it expression-agnostic

Comment: @VinnieCent No problem. `=]` Tick the V below the up/down arrows to mark it as accepted if it worked for you. Oh thanks Bergi, wasn't aware of that property. `x]`

Comment: I had to do reg.lastIndex = found.index+found[0].length; so it continues from the position right after the last match.

Comment: Note to self: this will not work if the global ("g") flag is not set for the RegExp. (`new RegExp("foo", "g")` or `/foo/g`)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get the direct result from `match`, but it is possible to produce the result via `RegExp.exec` and with some modification to the regex:

```
var regex = /A[0-9]+B[0-9]+Y(?=(:A[0-9]+B[0-9]+Y))/g;
var input = 'A1B1Y:A1B2Y:A1B3Y:A1B4Z:A1B5Y:A1B6Y:A1B7Y:A1B8Z:A1B9Y:A1B10Y:A1B11Y'
var arr;
var results = [];

while ((arr = regex.exec(input)) !== null) {
    results.push(arr[0] + arr[1]);
}
```

I used *zero-width* positive look-ahead `(?=pattern)` in order not to consume the text, so that the overlapping portion can be rematched.

Actually, it is possible to abuse `replace` method to do achieve the same result:

```
var input = 'A1B1Y:A1B2Y:A1B3Y:A1B4Z:A1B5Y:A1B6Y:A1B7Y:A1B8Z:A1B9Y:A1B10Y:A1B11Y'
var results = [];

input.replace(/A[0-9]+B[0-9]+Y(?=(:A[0-9]+B[0-9]+Y))/g, function ($0, $1) {
    results.push($0 + $1);
    return '';
});
```

However, since it is `replace`, it does extra useless replacement work.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it's not quite as simple as a single `string.match`.

The reason is that you want overlapping matches, which the `/g` flag doesn't give you.

You could use lookahead:

```
var re = /A\d+B\d+Y(?=:A\d+B\d+Y)/g;
```

But now you get:

```
string.match(re); // ["A1B1Y", "A1B2Y", "A1B5Y", "A1B6Y", "A1B9Y", "A1B10Y"]
```

The reason is that lookahead is zero-width, meaning that it just says whether the pattern comes after what you're trying to match or not; it doesn't include it in the match.

You could use `exec` to try and grab what you want. If a regex has the `/g` flag, you can run `exec` repeatedly to get all the matches:

```
// using re from above to get the overlapping matches

var m;
var matches = [];
var re2 = /A\d+B\d+Y:A\d+B\d+Y/g; // make another regex to get what we need

while ((m = re.exec(string)) !== null) {
  // m is a match object, which has the index of the current match
  matches.push(string.substring(m.index).match(re2)[0]);
}

matches == [
  "A1B1Y:A1B2Y", 
  "A1B2Y:A1B3Y", 
  "A1B5Y:A1B6Y", 
  "A1B6Y:A1B7Y", 
  "A1B9Y:A1B10Y", 
  "A1B10Y:A1B11Y"
];
```

[Here's a fiddle of this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/jWzfM/). Open up the console to see the results

Alternatively, you could split the original string on `:`, then loop through the resulting array, pulling out the the ones that match when `array[i]` and `array[i+1]` both match like you want.