# JavaScript RegExp not giving desired result

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find and replace variables from a JavaScript code.

Lets say I need to search "length" in given code, I want to exclude "x.length" or "linelength"

Sample input - to make it easier to debug

```
var sampleStringWhichWorks = 'function checkLength(l, ls){\n' +
    'var line, lines, len, length01, linelength11;\n' +
    'line = l;\n' +
    'lines = ls;\n' +
    'len = line.length12;\n' +
    'length02 = lines.length13;\n' +
    'if(len==length03){\n' +
        'len--;\n' +
        'length04= length05 + 1;\n' +
        '}\n' +
    'linelength14 = len + length06;\n' +
    'return linelength15;\n' +
'}\n';
```

This /([^a-z.])length[\d]{2}([^a-z])/mig expression solves the problem, but for lines like "length04=length05 + 1" it only captures the first length and ignores second.

It does work for "length04 = length05 + 1" and captures both instances.

I have added [\d]{2} just for better understanding, expected outcome here is to capture all the 'length' ending with 0 and ignore ending with 1.

I tried other options like specifying like [^a-z]{0,1}, but not solving the problem.

Check the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bhosale_ajay/x6ARj/).

Actual input and regex (/([^a-z.])length([^a-z])/mig)

```
function checkLength(l, ls){
    var line, lines, len, length, lineLength;
    line = l;
    lines = ls;
    len = line.length;
    length = lines.length;
    if(len == length){
        len--;
        length=length+1;
    }
    lineLength = len + length;
    return lineLength;
}
```

Expected outcome from this

1. var line, lines, len, **length**, lineLength;
2. **length** = lines.length;
3. if(len == **length**){
4. **length** = **length** + 1;
5. lineLength = len + **length**;

Comment: You can also use http://www.cyber-reality.com/regexy.html to test the regex quickly

Comment: I have to tell you, I'm not reading this not because I don't want to help, but because there's ten different text styles in thirty lines.  Gives me a headache, sorry.

Comment: @Steve - point taken, edited

Comment: What *exactly* are you allowing before/after `length0x`? Dots seem to be forbidden but equals signs allowed - what's the rule here? Regexes are all about rules. You need to define them precisely.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Before : any thing than [a-z] and '.'; After : any thing than [a-z]

Comment: So what lines are you expecting from your new edit you posted?

Comment: @hwnd - I have updated the question with desired outcome, the regexp should capture total 6 'length'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match `length` if and only if it's not preceded by `[a-z.]` and not succeeded by `[a-z]`, then you can use this:

```
/(^|[^a-z.])length(?![a-z])/mig
```

**Explanation:**

```
(^|[^a-z.]) # Match either the start of the line or a char other than [a-z.]
length      # Match "length0"
(?![a-z])   # Assert that there is no [a-z] following the current match
```

Note that the regex will have to capture the character before `length` if the match occurs anywhere else but the start of the string. This is unavoidable due to JavaScript's lamentable lack of support for lookbehind assertions. So you need to check the length of your match, and chop off the first character if the length is 7.

Comment: actaul code will not have length01 or length11, i have added to make them easier to count, and to explain my problem

Comment: @AjayBhosale: This answer *is* using lookahead assertions. Did you try it?

Answer (score 3):

The issue that you have is that regular expression matches begins at the end of the previous match and as you can see on this sample :

```
([^a-z.])length[\d]{2}([^a-z])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7k96iRugJkqZuG7p)

`length05` is not being captured because the `=` signs before it is already taken by the previous match...

So you can use the method indicated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14863268/1127669) :

```
var regex = /([^a-z.])length[\d]{2}([^a-z])/mig

var matches = [], found;
while (found = regex.exec(string)) {
    matches.push(found[0]);
    regex.lastIndex = found.index+1;
}

console.log(matches);
```

You can see it in action in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/x6ARj/3/

---

**EDIT :**

In response to your comment, if you want to replace the string, one solution is to use the `slice` method using `found.index` and `regex.lastIndex` indexes :

```
var replacement = "name", 
    regex = /([^a-z.])length([\d]{2}[^a-z])/mi,
    matches = [], found;

while (found = regex.exec(string)) {
    string = string.slice(0, found.index) + found[1] + replacement + found[2] + string.slice(regex.lastIndex);
    regex.lastIndex = found.index+1;
}

console.log(string);
```

Comment: +1, Excellent, Thanks a lot, I also thought that the = is getting captured by earlier match, I now need to think how i can use it to replace it ... I was using '$1SOME-OTHER-NAMKE-INSTEAD-OF-LENGTH$2'

Comment: You mean a dynamical name, like this : `var name = "some_name", regex = new RegExp("([^a-z.])" + name + "[\\d]{2}([^a-z])", "mig");`.

Comment: yes, i want to replace "some_name" with "some_other_name" while keeping the captured parts, so i was doing code.replace(regex,'$1some_other_name$2') to replace "some_name" with "some_other_name"

Comment: @AjayBhosale: Note that lookahead assertions remove the need for any "manual resetting" of the match's index counter precisely because the lookahead doesn't participate in the actual match.

Comment: I agree with @TimPietzcker comment for this example (here we don't really need a validation on an extra character) but for some cases, we NEED this extra character in the regex, and in this case, this question is pertinent!

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Thanks for the pointers, I will explore lookahead assertions and see if i can get desired results without resetting index.

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie - As edited answer by Tim Pietzcker is more accurate i am going to change accepted answer, hope you are fine with this ...

Comment: No problem, as indicated above, I agree too with this solution, but I let mine as it can't be avoided in some problems!